# c# how to save an xml file in a different folder than app/bin/debug/

Tags: c#, xml, save

I just wanted to know if there's a way of saving an XML file containing chart data into a specific folder. I've got a button called SAVED that saves a png or jpeg file of the current state of the chart and saves an xml file of this chart in order to load it later. The problem is that that file goes by default into app/bin/debug/myXMLfile.xml

```
graph.SaveImage(save.FileName, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageFormat.Png);
graph.Serializer.Save(txtNom.Text + "_" + txtPrenom.Text + ".xml");
```

Comment: you should be able to save in a different folder by specifying the path. `chart1.SaveImage("C:\\myfolder\\mychart.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving a specified path by you to the method "save"??

For Ex

```
graph.Serializer.Save(C:\\txtNom.Text + "_" + txtPrenom.Text + ".xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with

```
graph.Serializer.Save(save.FileName+".xml");
```

but i've got something ugly like myFile.png.xml so i just use the substring method in order to just get hte name of the file without the .png extention and then i add the xml extention. It give something like this

```
 graph.Serializer.Save(save.FileName.Substring(0,save.FileName.IndexOf('.')) + ".xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to prompt the user for each file using a common function.  You will need to add references to these libraries in your form's code-behind section:

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
```

Then add the event handler for the Save button and the common function for prompting the user for full file paths:

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string imageFilePath = null;
        string dataFilePath = null;
        ImageFormat format = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png;

        try
        {
            // Image data
            imageFilePath = promptForFilePath("Save Chart image", "PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPEG Files (*.jpg,*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|BMP Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|All Files (*.*)|*.*");

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(imageFilePath))
            {
                switch (Path.GetExtension(imageFilePath).Replace(".", "").ToLower())
                {
                    case "jpeg":
                    case "jpg": 
                                format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                        break;
                    case "png": format = ImageFormat.Png;
                        break;
                    case "bmp": format = ImageFormat.Bmp;
                        break;
                }

                this.graph.SaveImage(imageFilePath, format);
            }

            // XML data
            dataFilePath = promptForFilePath("Save Chart data","XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml|All Files (*.*)|*.*");

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataFilePath)) this.graph.Serializer.Save(dataFilePath);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:  " + ex.Message, "btnSave_Click Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }

    string promptForFilePath(string title = "Save File", string fileFilter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*")
    {
        string result = null;
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = null;

        try
        {
            saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.Title = title;
            saveFileDialog.Filter = fileFilter;

            if(saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                result = saveFileDialog.FileName; 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:  " + ex.Message, "saveChartData Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (saveFileDialog != null)
            {
                saveFileDialog.Dispose();
                saveFileDialog = null;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```